# There is any way Download Excel file from web page using android webview without empty file

Tags: android, excel, webview, download

I can download excel file by below code from my android webview app but file exporting empty excel. Same file download from chrome or other browser exporting excel file with content (Working good). There is any way to exporting excel file with content from a webpage with webview App. If any one help me than my project will complete and i can sell it or i am hanging here.

//Runtime External storage permission for saving download files

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it");
            String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permissions, 1);
        }
    }


    //handle downloading
    web_view.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength) -> {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                Uri.parse(url));
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);

        String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
        request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
        request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
        request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                        url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "See Notification. Downloading File. Go to Download folder from File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });


}
```

Comment: `Download Excel file from web page` ? From a webserver i would say.

Comment: `without empty file.` ? What would that be?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.